# Europa4: how scenarios are different?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

What is the difference in Europa 4 scenarios?

Let's take 2 first: "Rise of the Ottomans" and "Empires of the Sands" - start date and set of countries look the same. The only visual difference is list of "interesting countries". Even countries in America are the same.

What is the real difference? May be goals for the games?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only differences in the game are different starting situations for nations caused by different start dates that will give you a historically correct-ish start instead of the more random situation you get by running the simulator.

There is no difference between the four scenarios that start in 1444, both in my experience and supported in the [wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Scenarios) entry for this topic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. They only direct your attention to the different regions of the game. And the game doesn't have a singular goal. Only you can decide what kind of empire you want to build.

Comment: Thank you. It that a personal opinion there are references to confirm?

Comment: Richard ten Brink gave you the same answer and also a link to the game wiki. This should provide enough proof.